# RSpec, wrong parametrs in method post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I test password recovery, but there are errors.
Rspec study recently.

code (User Controller)

```
def forgot
  if request.post?
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    if user
      user.create_reset_code
    end
    flash[:notice] = t('helpers.notice_email')
    render :template => "sessions/new"
  end
end
```

rspec test

```
it "POST 'reset page'" do
  User.should_receive(:find_by_email).with({:email => @user.email})
  post :forgot, :user => {"email" => @user.email}
end
```

What am I doing wrong in the test?

Comment: Can you paste in the errors you're getting?

Comment: Failure/Error: post :forgot, :user => {"email" => @user.email}
       <User(id: integer, name: string, email: string, encrypted_password: string, salt: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, admin: boolean, reset_code: string) (class)> received :find_by_email with unexpected arguments
         expected: ({:email=>"email13@example.com"})
              got: ("email13@example.com")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.should_receive(:find_by_email).with(@user.email)
```